# statement for npgsql using parameter

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

I pass the parameters in the sql query using the driver npgsql:

```
SqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand();
....
SqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT id,name FROM table1 WHERE field1=:param2 ORDER BY name;";
SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", 1);
```

This query executed correctly and issued the necessary data, but as soon as I add parameter to the sql in the section "select"

```
SqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT id,name :param1 FROM table1 WHERE field1=:param2 ORDER BY name;";
SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", ",field1");
SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", 1);
```

it gives me some kind of nonsense. In theory this request to the server is to be treated as

```
SELECT id,name,field1 FROM table1 WHERE field1=1 ORDER BY name;
```

but it did not happen.
This raises the question: is there a way to dynamically insert a list of fields using suchlike parameters?

Comment: That's not how parameterized queries work at all, in *any* database that supports them (instead of faking them). They represent *values*, not string substitutions. If you put a parameter in `SELECT` you should get back the parameter's value

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Npgsql doesn't have support for what you are trying to do. NpgsqlParameter values are supposed to be only used as parameter values in the where clause. 
In order to add field names dynamically as you intend, you will have to create the query manually by using string concatenation.

I hope it helps.

Comment: What is the recommended way to add dynamic values without risking SQL injection? For example, how would I add a dynamic value in a function call which has no WHERE clause?

Comment: @SteveGlick use LINQ and an ORM or microORM to generate the statement, or be very, very, very careful when constructing the query, eg generate *only* the `SELECT` statement after validating that the supplied values are actually fields of the table.

Answer (score -2):

Rewrite you CommandText and add this:

```
foreach (NpgsqlParameter item in _Command.Parameters)
{
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.ParameterName, item.Value);
}
```

And solve your problem..