# postgresql escape string in c#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a problem with the escape sequence of postgresql. Use npgsql and c#
I use this code for my query:

```
cResult = Regex.Replace(cStringa, @"(\\)([\000\010\011\012\015\032\042\047\134\140])", "$2");
```

But if I enter the ' character I get an error string does not comply.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you escaping rather than using parameterized SQL anyway? Can you give us more detail about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am posting a record in the database with a query:
insert into table values('1', '2', 'd'altro'). The string d'altro It is created with the regex function.

Comment: So stop doing that. Use parameterized SQL instead.

Comment: Ok, but do not know them, I will try a few examples ...Thank you

Comment: @JonSkeet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482569/statement-for-npgsql-using-parameter because of this. I need N number of sort which I need to add into query dynamically.

Comment: That's not what the OP wants to do in this question though, and should be handled a different way, IMO.